# Validate empty select in controller?

Tags: validation, grails, controller

I have a view that has a select list on it as shown below:

```
<g:select name="Field_time" from="${["00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09"] + (10..23)}" value="${timeHr}" noSelection="['':'-Time-']"/>
```

Now when the user does not select anything from the list and the "NoSelection" value is set I would expect the param to store "" as its data on the forms submit. So I then went on to trying to validate if the data in this select field is empty on my controller as couldn’t do it on the domain as this data never hits the domain, so I had this code below:

```
if(params.Field_time.size() == 0 || params.Field_time == "" || params.Field_time == null){

            println("Inside the validate select function")
        }
```

I also check all of the params to see what was being returned in that object and the data is below:

```
Field_time:[, ]
```

So when I run the code I was expecting it to print the message to the screen however it doesn’t :S

I presume that I am checking the wrong things in the IF statement and was maybe thinking I would need to split the params returned object up first but not sure, I would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you may have multiple elements with the same name `Field_time` remove them and try it again.

Comment: That wasn't the issue I was on the right lines with my thought of splitting the array, iv sorted it now :)

Comment: I'm glad its resolved. but normally if you only have a unique name the params should look like `Field_time:` not `Field_time:[, ]`. Anyway glad you resolved it.